# How should I add a file in my LaTeX document?

Tags: pdfpages, include

I am creating my BE project report using LaTeX and in that I have to add my sponsorship letter. Is there any solution to do this?

Answer (score 5):

If your sponsorship letter is a pdf, then you can use the following package:

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

And then use the following where you want to insert the letter:

```
\includepdf[pages={1}]{letter.pdf}
```

Comment: I tried the above solution and it's working......

Comment: @user2846210 please mark the answer that you like most to close the question.

Answer (score 3):

In menu bar select LaTex menu, in that select `\include{file}` and then browse to find the file you want to include (and file should be Tex file).

(If file to be include is a pdf file) and james Shaeffer is right if u want to add pdf file.

first include package

```
\usepackage{pdfpages}
```

and then to include file

```
\includepdf[pages={1}]{letter.pdf}`
```